# Relation between $A_{n-1}$ and $A_n$ in a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Found this in a math textbook:

If the relationship between terms $a_{n-1}$ and $a_n$ in a sequence is $3a_n = 2a_{n-1} +1$, then what is $a_{n+1}$?

I am confused on how to solve this problem since we are not given any terms of the sequence, so can someone guide me through this?

Comment: I guess you can try to write $a_{n+1}$ in terms of $a_0$?

Comment: I don't see what you can possibly do other than the above comment if available, or simply shift the indices up by one to get $a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{3}(2a_{n} +1)$.

Comment: @Nishant How would you write $a_{n+1}$ in terms of $a_0$?

Comment: Elaqqad's answer should help.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider $u_n=a_n-1$ and prove that:
$$u_{n+1}=\frac{2}{3}u_n $$